# Short cut for ref in latex

Tags: cross-referencing, shortcut

I am writing my thesis. Therefore,  I need to use `\ref{}`. Sometimes I would like to use `( )` such that:

`(\ref{})`. As you know, for citation, we can use `\citep` to get this `(authour 1980)`. I would like to know if there is a shortcut for `\ref` as well. That is, is there a convenient way to get `(\ref{})` automatically.

Comment: `\eqref` from amsmath?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you a lot. Could you please pass it as an answer?

Comment: You could make your own?`\def\refp#1{\ref{#1}}`

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman what does #1 mean?

Comment: That's the argument. You can read more about macros and commands [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros).

Comment: I forgot you're parentheses, so `\def\refp#1{(\ref{#1})}` is what you're looking for, then you can do `\refp{ref:somewhere}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This form with `( )` is usually used for equation numbers and `amsmath` provides `\eqref` which does exactly what you ask. Or more exactly it uses the same format as the package uses for equation numbers, so `( )` by default but if you change that then both the equation and the reference will use the same formatting.

Answer (score 5):

As the accepted answer by @DavidCarlisle says, `\eqref` from `amsmath` is the way to go, since it takes care of the format such that it matches `amsmath`s equation numbering. However, you could make your own:

```
% Make a new command that makes your \refp
\newcommand{\refp}[1]{(\ref{#1})}
```

The square brackets `[1]` is how many arguments the command takes,
and the `#1` is the argument itself. So now when you do `\refp{some:ref}`
it replaces it with `(\ref{some:ref})`
All you have to do to use it is then

```
\refp{some:ref}
```

Comment: I really thought there is no solution and my question will have no answer.

Comment: Wow. There are so many things you can learn about LaTeX. So many things. Here's something to get you started:
[Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) and
[LaTeX-tutorial](https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/first-document/)

Comment: why `\def` not `\newcommand` here? (especially for a beginner it would be better to suggest the latex form)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the Wikibook, nor the tutorials site.

Comment: Oh. Why not? What would you recommend?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are of course right. I just mostly use `\def`myself, and should have thought about this. Changed the answer to fix this :)

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6393/how-can-we-as-a-community-improve-the-latex-wikibook